# Would you tell me the difference between object and objective as a noun?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, meaning, conundrum

I am very confused. Could you possibly elaborate (*in detail*) **the reason** why:

> My object is to *improve* my English as much as possible. [*WRONG it should be 'objective'*]
>
> My object is to learn English. [*RIGHT*]
>
> The object of the game is to *improve* children's math skill. [*RIGHT*]

So, why has Longman written the following:

> **!** Do not use *object* to mean 'the thing you are working towards and hope to achieve'.  Use *objective*: We have not yet achieved our objective (NOT our object).

Is Longman here wrong?

All of the expressions and examples which I have provided are extracted from Longman (see link below) and Common Errors from Longman too.

http://www.ldoceonline.com/Grammar-topic/object_1

Comment: This question brought to you by ELL: [question one](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22250/would-you-at-this-situation-explain-the-difference-between-object-and-objective) - [question two](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20031/what-is-the-difference-between-object-and-objective)

Comment: In addition, this question is so different with the one at another place.

Comment: That's fussy and unhelpful advice. Those are indeed meanings that can be used, but there are other meanings, too. In particular, _object_ is often used instead of _objective_, if the point is clear and there's no reason to distinguish the two. Following this and similar overfussy advice about "correctness" only produces needless anxiety. Once you learn that anybody can write anything at all about what's "correct" in English -- no matter how silly it is -- and somebody will read and believe it -- no matter how silly it is -- you will understand that you needn't care about things like this.

Comment: I just wanted to ask if the lack of spacing before a ( and the spacing after it is a thing that has developed out of habit, especially for Indians. It's not *elaborate( in detail)...* it's *elaborate (in detail)...* it's not just you, I've seen this consistently in 'raw' material out of India.

Comment: @JohnLawler My object all sublime, I shall achieve in time ...

Comment: Where is it written in the Longman Dictionary that "My **object is to improve** my English..." is WRONG? I have spent some time looking. Can you provide the link for Longman's *common errors* I can't  find it.

Comment: I repeat. Where in The Longman Dictionary does it say that **My object is to improve my English as much as possible** is *WRONG*?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: It doesn't because it can't. There's nothing wrong with that sentence, unless one is enforcing a matter of personal taste, or being paid to enforce one. The Longman Dictionary is usually fairly reliable about syntax. They seem to pay attention to data, rather than tradition.

Comment: @JohnLawler I agree, I wish I had looked earlier in LDOCE though; the OP in their first example claims that LDOCE suggests using *objective* in place of *object*. Well, as far as I could tell, LDOCE doesn't. Anywhere. The other two examples are provided under the entry of *object*, if for Longman "My object is to learn English" is acceptable and contemporary in usage, so too the first example.

Comment: @JohnLawler  I think Longman is trying to say  *objective* is the preferred term in sentences such as: *He achieved his objective of winning a Grand Slam* or *The investors' failed to accomplish their objective* I would avoid using *object* in those cases, but I can't explain why. Maybe it has something to do with "achieve" and "accomplish"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Yes, I think it's the verbs. They're the first thing one should suspect with something like that. Don't know why, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Longman says "Do not use object to mean 'the thing you are working towards and hope to achieve" and provided "My object is to learn English" as an example, then it is contradicting itself. As for the object-objective distinction, I can only offer an opinion:

1. **Objective can be used in any situation where object can be used**, i.e. "what's the *objet* of the game" → "what's the *objective* of the game"
2. **Object can only be used to describe the *main* goal of something**. For this reason, you can say "the object of my visit is to return your book" or "the object of the game is to pick up the most sticks" but not "my object is to learn English" because in the first two, you are describing the central goal of the visit or game, while in the third, you are only describing one of your many goals.

Comment: There are several problems with this as an answer. First, it's not clear as to what you mean by "contradicting itself" in your first paragraph. It's not contradictory, just a poor word choice to express its meaning. Second, objective cannot be used in every place where object (even with this meaning) can.

Comment: @virmaior (1) You disagree that in the sentence "My object is to learn English," object means "the thing you are working towards and hope to achieve"? The speaker is working towards _learning English_. (2) Can you provide an example where you can use object (in this meaning of course) and not objective?

Comment: (1) I don't disagree that the speaker/writer *intends* it to have that meaning. It is however not a construction native speakers would make. (2) I don't know what you mean by "this meaning" -- at best you are trying to argue by repeating the claim you are arguing for. The ways you are defining object / objective are non-standard.

Answer (score 9):

The distinction Longman draws is entirely artificial and does not reflect actual use in any register. *Object* has been used continuously since the 17th century to mean ‘the thing you are working towards and hope to achieve’, and it is used so today. You may satisfy yourself of this by searching [Google Books for 21st-century instances of "our object is to"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our+object+is+to%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22our+object+is+to%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099); alongside reprinted older works you will find scores of uses—in mathematics, philosophy, history, law, politics, art, literary criticism, and fiction. You will find similar results with various combinations of *achieve* and *object*.

If you are of a prescriptivist bent, consult Fowler, *Modern English Usage*. He says nothing about a distinction between *object* and *objective*; but his parade sentence for discussion of the split infinitive is

> Our object is to further cement trade relations.

The best advice you have seen here is John Lawler’s:

> Following this and similar overfussy advice about "correctness" only produces needless anxiety. Once you learn that anybody can write anything at all about what's "correct" in English—no matter how silly it is—and somebody will read and believe it—no matter how silly it is—you will understand that you needn't care about things like this.

Answer (score 2):

An **objective** is something you want to pursue.

> My objective is to improve my coordination.

An **object** of a thing is the purpose for which it exists.

> The object of billiards in school is to teach coordination.

An *object* is internal to the thing. An *objective* is something that can come from a being. So only people and persons can have objectives whereas objects and people can have an object.

This is exactly what is expressed by the quote from Longman:

> Do not use object to mean 'the thing you are working towards and hope to achieve'. Use     objective:  We have not yet achieved our objective (NOT our object).

Your attempts to produce sentences with this grammar are basically wrong.

> My object is to improve my English as much as possible (**probably comprehensible but wrong**)

Unless you are a being that exists solely to improve English, then this is wrong. You should use objective.

> My object is to learn English (**incorrect**)

Again, unless you exist to maximize your English learning, then this is wrong.

> The object of the game is to improve children's math skill. (**correct**)

This is correct because the game is made for this purpose, so we can call that purpose its object.

Comment: Thanks. Nevertheless, you said Longman is right, but on the other hands you said MY OBJECT IS TO LEARN ENGLISH is incorrect.I suppose you even didn't understand well what you were thinking about.

Comment: @nima_persian Unless you are a computer program designed to master English, the sentence *my object is to learn English* is incorrect. Without suggesting a purpose for human life, I can say that I don't think it is mastering a second language.

Comment: I think virmaior that nima-persian has interpreted "My object is to learn English" as the *correct version* of the previous example. You should sign post which phrases are "less acceptable" or "inaccurate" (for greater clarity) for example with a *NO* at the end. It has to be something visible and unambiguous otherwise other visitors might believe you are contradicting yourself.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I've tried to make some edits... I think nima_persian is probably better fit for ell than here...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, when you asked us to elaborate, you would ask us to elaborate 'in detail', not 'in details'.  Secondly, I would question that the use of 'object' in either the first or second sentence is preferable.  Thirdly, you were right to question Longman, as I would dispute the conclusions you have mentioned.

To begin, 'object' and 'objective' can sometimes be used interchangeably.  In some contexts, neither is more correct than the other.  However, it can sometimes come down to what sounds best, which is fairly confusing (and unfair!) for a learner.

The word 'object', used in its noun form to mean a goal or purpose, would generally be used in a sentence thusly:

> *The object of this sentence is to give you an example.*
>
> *This sentence was written with the object of providing you an example.*

Note that the phrase 'the object of' appears in both sentences.  Some nouns must be paired with a preposition in order to better demonstrate to what they actually relate.  While the word 'object' can be used as a normal noun in other sentence structures, the two examples I have provided above require that 'the object' be paired with 'of'.

Compare this noun + preposition relationship to your own sentences.  While the use of the word 'object' is not grammatically *wrong* per se, it is simply not as common or as *natural* to use 'object'.  I would personally reword your sentences to:

> *My goal/objective/aim is to improve my English as much as possible.*
>
> *My goal/objective/aim is to learn English.*

Using 'my objective' is correct in both instances, as the sentence structure remains the same, regardless of the verb you use.  However, using 'my object' sounds a little awkward.  Not wrong, just awkward.

Your third sentence 'The object of the game is to improve children's math skill' adheres to the noun + preposition relationship I mentioned above, making clear that the noun 'the object' refers to 'the game'.  Your sentence is entirely acceptable.

It is also worthwhile to mention that the noun 'object' is mostly (but not exclusively) paired with the word 'the' rather than 'my'.

> ***The** object of this experiment is to split atoms.*
>
> *The safe release of the hostages was **the** object of the highly secret mission.*

However, when 'object' does appear paired with 'my' (or another possessive determiner such as 'her', 'his' or 'our'), it is also accompanied by a preposition, such as 'in'.  For example:

> *My object **in** coming here was to return this book I borrowed.*

However, as I said before, it does sound a little awkward being used in such a way and the word 'purpose' would preferable.

So, all in all, 'object' and 'objective' do share the same meaning here and can sometimes be interchangeable.  However, determining which is best to use sometimes relies on context, sentence structure, possessive determiners and prepositions.

I hope that helped!

Comment: Would you please compare your idea with Longman ( the link which I already provided above?

Answer (score 0):

> **An objective** is something you want to pursue.
>
> ```
> My objective is to improve my coordination.
> ```
>
> **An object** of a thing is the purpose for which it exists.
>
> ```
> The object of billiards in school is to teach coordination.
> ```

An object of a thing/action is the purpose for which it exists/gets carried out.

An objective is a further specification of the Object. Kinda like the clause with its adverbs. Its "why" if you may.